# Variable '' is used before it has been assigned a value.

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to make a program that downloads a bunch of domains and adds them windows hosts file but I'm having a bit of trouble. I keep getting an error when I try storing them in a list. I don't get why it doesn't work.

```
Sub Main()
    Console.Title = "NoTrack blocklist to Windows Hosts File Converter"
    Console.WriteLine("Downloading . . . ")
    Dim FileDelete As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile) & "/Downloads" & "/notracktemp.txt"
    If System.IO.File.Exists(FileDelete) = True Then
        System.IO.File.Delete(FileDelete)
    End If
    download()
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    Dim s As New IO.StreamReader(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile) & "/Downloads" & "/notracktemp.txt", True)
    Dim tempRead As String ' = s.ReadLine
    Dim tempSplit As String() ' = tempRead.Split(New Char() {" "})
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim tempStore As String()
    s.ReadLine()
    s.ReadLine()
    Do Until s.EndOfStream = True
        tempRead = s.ReadLine
        tempSplit = tempRead.Split(New Char() {" "})
        Console.WriteLine(tempSplit(0))
        tempStore(i) = tempSplit(0)'The part that gives me the error
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub


Sub download()
    Dim localDir As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile)
    '"Enter file URL"
    Dim url As String = "https://quidsup.net/notrack/blocklist.php?download"
    '"Enter directory"
    Dim dirr As String = localDir & "/Downloads" & "/notracktemp.txt"
    My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(url, dirr)
    'System.IO.File.Delete(localDir & "/notracktemp.txt")
End Sub
```

Comment: You never redim `tempStore()` to have a size.

Comment: Right, ya, I forgot xD

Comment: of the 118 million Google matches, there is this [Variable '<variablename>' is used before it has been assigned a value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/error-messages/variable-variablename-is-used-before-it-has-been-assigned-a-value).  Also a `List` is different than an array

Answer (score 0):

tempStore() has to have a size
count number of lines in file with loop, then declare it as tempStore(i) where i is the amount of lines. Here is a function that counts the lines.

```
    Function countlines()
    Dim count As Integer
    Dim s As New IO.StreamReader(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile) & "/Downloads" & "/notracktemp.txt", True)
    s.ReadLine()
    s.ReadLine()
    count = 0
    Do Until s.EndOfStream = True
        s.ReadLine()
        count = count + 1
    Loop
    Console.WriteLine(count)
    Return count
    Console.ReadKey()
End Function
```

Then what you do is:

```
    Dim count As Integer
    count = countlines()

    Dim tempStore(count) As String
```

Comment: Not a good answer because you dont actually show the solution